# Currency symbol is changing but value does not change

Tags: magento-1.9

In my work the curreny symbol is changing when i change the currency but the value remains same

Comment: Go to Admin->system->Manage currency->Rates. And there you need to set rates for your currency compared to your base price. Like if the base price is dollar then How much is EURO compared to Dollar. Like that.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Admin > system > Manage currency > Rates.

There will be only one rate filled for your base currency and all other currency has the blank value. So now you need to enter rates for all currency compare to your base currency. Like if the base price is dollar then How much is EURO compared to 1 Dollar.

**Example:**

Your Base currency is USD = 1

Second currency Euro = 0.94     // Compared to 1 Dollar

**Note:** Compare each currency rate with base currency before filled.

When complete, click the Save Currency Rates button.

Or you can go through http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/store-operations/currency-rates-update.html